# How do I create a bunch of tasks in a loop

Tags: c#

I have a list of 100 values

I want to spawn 5 threads to process 20 each

my code is basically

```
for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
{

   Task.Run(() => {
       myMethod(myList.Skip(i * 20).Take(20)));
   });
}
```

Obviously because this closes over the value of i, it can totally screw it up. I've tried everything I can think of to get it to capture the value at the time the task is declared but I am having no luck at all. Even setting the first line of the Task.Run to `var localVariable = i;` to capture it does not work, it runs the method and i is 5 every time.

How do I do this, presumably I want to create the task by passing in the value of i so it never looks outside the function but I can't figure out how to do this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're nearly there, but *as well* as creating a copy of the local variable, you need to use it in your lambda expression:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
   int localCopy = i;
   Task.Run(() => {
       myMethod(myList.Skip(localCopy * 20).Take(20)));
   });
}
```

If that doesn't work, then the problem *isn't* the variable capture - it's elsewhere.

Of course, another option is to use `Parallel.ForEach` with a custom partitioner, or something like that. In other words, there may well be better ways of approaching the problem.

Comment: Yes, this does not work. I assume because the loop is so fast that it does Task.Run 5 times before it even gets chance to run once.

Comment: @SLC: "does not work" doesn't give us any information, but it definitely *does* work in terms of running 5 tasks, one of which will call `Skip(0)`, one of which will call `Skip(20)`, one of which will call `Skip(40)` etc. As I say in the answer, if this code doesn't work then you need to look for the problem elsewhere. (We don't have enough context to help any further...)

Comment: It seems to be an intermittent issue, perhaps it is fixed. Can you explain why this works, if the task scheduler was to start the first task, iterate, and start the 2nd task, and then the task scheduler switches to the first task and executes the first line of code, surely i would be 1 or 2 or more depending on what point it got switched to?

Comment: I think you're right that the actual issue lies elsewhere, I suspect myMethod is doing some thread unsafe stuff. I guess c# must close over the variable at the time the task is define by intelligently working out what variables we're going to need within the task?

Comment: @SLC: In my copy of the code, `i` isn't used within the task at all. Instead, the copy of the value of `i` for that iteration is used. I'm not quite sure what you're asking in the second comment, but the C# compiler honours scope, so the `localCopy` in the first iteration of the loop is a *separate variable* to the `localCopy` in the second iteration of the loop. Different variables will be captured by the lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `var localVariable = i` outside the Task.